# Which node in a MarkLogic cluster runs the CPF Action Module?

Tags: marklogic

I have a MArkLogic cluster with 3 nodes:

1. **Node 1**
2. **Node 2**
3. **Node 3**

On this clustered environemnt I have a database **test** which has one forest **test-01**.
The *Primary Host* for the forest **test-01** is on **Node 1**. Also, I have CPF installed on the database **test**

Now, when I insert any document in the database **test**, the CPF action module will be executed on which Node's Task Server thread?

Will the *Primary Host* of the forest in which the document gets created **ALWAYS** executes the CPF action module?

What If I configure a failover replica of forest **test-01** on **Node 2** and **Node 3** and after that stop the MarkLogic service on **Node 01**. which Node's Task Server will then execute the CPF action modules?

Answer (score 3):

CPF uses triggers. A pre-commit trigger will fire on the same host that processes the update. This is independent of forest and cluster configuration. A post-commit trigger will run on the Task Server on the host with the affected forest *(thanks to John Snelson for correcting my understanding on this point)*.

CPF actions use both kinds of triggers. So if you want to limit triggers to a single host, ensure that all your updates are processed on that host **and** ensure all the affected forests are on that same host. You'd also want to handle host failover by moving update traffic to the next host.

CPF also uses the database online event, which is a little different. I believe that can run on any host, but it may be limited to hosts with any forests attached to the database.

Comment: After installing CPF on the database and going with the default triggers created in the triggers database when I insert a document, how can I ensure that this _update is processed on a specific host_ of a cluster? Also, can you please explain the statement _"A trigger will fire on the same **host that processes the update**."_

Comment: When you send an update request to a host, that host processes the update. During the commit phase it handles any pre-commit triggers. After that it spawns tasks for post-commit triggers.

Comment: I am new to MarkLogic and its way of sending/ handling requests. What I am doing is a simple `xdmp:document-insert("sample.xml", <sample></sample>, (), ("test"))` and I have a CPF domain defined on "test" collection. In this scenario is there any way I can control on the host the CPF trigger gets fired and eventually which node's Task Server thread is used?

Comment: Actually since MarkLogic 5 post-commit triggers have been run on the D-node that hosts the data that caused the trigger. So the majority of CPF work will be run on the D-node that has the forest which contains the document.

Comment: Thanks, John: I edited to incorporate that. @Rahul I'm not sure how you'd be in doubt about where your queries are running, but `xdmp:host-name(xdmp:host())` will tell you.

Comment: CPF indeed uses both pre-commit and post-commit triggers. The pre-commit triggers are to capture status changes like update, delete, create. Those pre-commit triggers will kick off the post-commit triggers that will make docs go through the CPF states of pipelines. States is were the real action is..