# How to spread Task Server threads across all nodes of a MarkLogic cluster?

Tags: marklogic

I have a 3 node cluster in MarkLogic 7. I have created a database "sample-db" which has the following forests:

1. sample-db-01 hosted on *node-1*
2. sample-db-02 hosted on *node-2*
3. sample-db-03 hosted on *node-3*

Now, from the *qconsole* I run the following FLWOR expression:

```xq
for $i in 1 to 20000
return
  xdmp:spawn-function(function(){
      xdmp:document-insert(xs:string($i), <sample>{xdmp:host-name()}</sample>),
      xdmp:commit()
  }, 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <transaction-mode>update</transaction-mode>
  </options>)
```

The above expression inserts 20000 documents in the "sample-db". **But** when I look at the Task Server status I can see that only *node-1* is being used to process the tasks queued in the Task Server.

[image]

Is there any configuration or code change with which I can make all the three nodes participate in processing the queued tasks?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your recent questions I'd back up and describe the problem that your end users want to solve. Don't do it here: it's too broad. Post to the dev mailing list. Don't assume any particular solution: describe the user story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid Mike is right. Spawns and evals always run against the current host. Depending on your underlying need there are other ways to go about with this. If you are interested in spreading ingest load, with transformation, you could consider using MLCP. An alternative could be to use CPF or post-commit triggers. Those run against the host that manages the forest in which a doc ends up in.

You could also try to create a custom endpoint in ML and do http calls to that to have the spawns spread across the cluster, but I think I personally would probably prefer one of the other alternatives I mentioned.

HTH!

Comment: Just to clarify on the CPF alternative. When I install CPF on the database a set of pre-commit and post-commit triggers are created. As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106378/which-node-in-a-marklogic-cluster-runs-the-cpf-action-module#comment42732160_27110674) the pre-commit triggers will fire on the same host that processes the update and the post-commit triggers will fire on the D-node that hosts the data that caused the trigger. Please let me know in case this is not how the CPF triggers get executed. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. The pre-commit triggers handle low-level status changes, the post-commit triggers handle going through CPF states, which is were the actions get called.

Answer (score 3):

Tasks are host-specific. They spawn on the host that calls `xdmp:spawn`.

You could write a REST service that replaces `xdmp:spawn` and implement your own task distribution. Or find some other way to spawn those tasks across all your hosts.

Comment: Re posting the previous comment: I also tried taskbot to spread the Task Server threads across the cluster using the following code: `tb:list-segment-process( 1 to 20000, 1, "sample", function($list as item()+, $opts as map:map?) { tb:maybe-fatal(), for $i in $list return xdmp:document-insert(xs:string($i), <sample>{xdmp:host-name()}</sample>), xdmp:commit() }, (), $tb:OPTIONS-UPDATE)`

Comment: The README of taskbot explains it relies heavily on spawn and invoke. Same issue there..